# Testing Nonetype elements in a list

Tags: python, list, recursion, nonetype

I have this kind of a list  `inputs = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`
I want to evaluat if all elements are the same that is None:
if so return an empty list that is  []

What I have  tried so far doesn't seem to work:

`if all(inputs) is None:
    print([])
 else:
     print("somthing else"`

Comment: `all(x is None for x in inputs)`

Comment: what if one element is not None - print all the nones and the one element as is? `print( [a for a in inputs if a is not None] )` can be used to print only none-`None` elements of the list - for a list of all `None`s this equals `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all()` tells you if every element in the iterable you pass to it is `True`. So, `all([True, True, True])` would be True, but `all([True, False])` wouldn't.

If you want to see if all elements are `None`, this is what you need:

```
all(x is None for x in inputs)
```

What this does is use a generator to loop over all the values in `inputs`, checking if they are `None` and `all()` checks all those results and returns `True` if all of them are `True`.

Comment: But why in  a scenario like this  '  # inputs = [3,0, 1, 2,None]
 # print([i for i in inputs if i]) ` 0 is evaluated as None

Comment: It's not evaluated as `None`. `if i` will test whether `i` is truthy - check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

Inside `all`, you need to iterate over `inputs` and compare each element to `None` individually, *i.e.*:

```
if all(element is None for element in inputs):
    print([])
else:
    print("something else")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the elements of the list inside all(). This should help.

```
inputs = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

if all(i is None for i in inputs):
  print([])
else:
  print("Something Else")
```